# android studio regularly stops finding physical device on ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, adb

Android Studio works fine for awhile on Ubuntu. It shows my device which I use to test on. Eventually, I unplug it, come back, and plugin again, but Android Studio doesn't see it.

I fiddle with restarting adb, unplugging device, revoking authorizations, turning off/on USB debugging, reopening Android Studio, etc. Sometimes a combination of these will suddenly show the device, but usually I have to reboot the PC. With DDR5 RAM the reboot takes several minutes and then I have to reopen a ton of work as well.

The device is connected to the computer, and I can even remote inspect apps for development in Chrome. Android Studio simply refuses to see it.

What is causing it to have intermittent availability in Android Studio? Are there any logs I can look at to find what's going on?

Comment: If you have problems with adb and USB devices you should first check `lsusb` if the device is still present. Then `adb devices`. If there are problems `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`. I would execute all these commands on a terminal outside of Android Studio.

Comment: Robert, thanks for the suggestions. The device is present (can remote inspect apps with chrome, manage files on the device, etc). I have also killed the adb processes with the kill command, and android studio automatically restarts them. I tried wireless debugging for the first time, and it seems to work much better so I'm doing that. I would still like to figure out the USB debugging though.